# IIViewDeckController and presentViewController

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, iiviewdeckcontroller

I got iOS app, where i use `IIViewDeckController` for side controllers.

But when i try use `presentViewController` it lead to some strange effect: grey semi-transparent view over all screen.

For example choosing image for avatar.

In the beginning we got this screen:

[image]

Then we choosing new image with this code:

```
- (void)startCameraControllerWithSourceType:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType {
    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:sourceType]) {
        return;
    }
    UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    cameraUI.allowsEditing = YES;
    cameraUI.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

So you can see `presentViewController` here. And then i see my gallery:

[image]

You can see semi-transparent view over gallery.

And the same view after canceling/accepting photo on previous viewController:

[image]

Can you help me? How should i remove this semi-transparent view?

Thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid this shadow, use:

`[viewDeckController setShadowEnabled:NO]`

Comment: surprisingly the official README does not mention this.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple to remove shadow from IIViewDeckController.

```
[deckController setShadowEnabled:NO];
```